# Apache 410 Gone instructions not working with mod_alias nor mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

Apache 2.2 (on a server running cPanel) seems to be ignoring instructions to return a 410 status.

This happens for both mod_alias's Redirect (using `410` or `gone`) and mod_rewrite's RewriteRule (using `[G]`), being used inside a .htaccess file.

This works:

```
Redirect 302 /somewhere /gone
```

But this doesn't:

```
Redirect 410 /somewhere
```

That line is ignored (as if it had been commented) and the request falls through to other rules (which direct it to an unrelated generic error handling script).

Similarly, trying to use a RewriteRule with a [G] flag doesn't work, but the same rule rewriting to a script that generates a 410 does - so the rules aren't the problem and it seems instead to be something about 410/gone that isn't behaving.

I can workaround it by having a script sending the 410, but that's annoying and I don't get why it's not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in cPanel - it requires an explicit ErrorDocument for the 410 to take effect.

So, the solution is to add the following to the .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 410 default
```

This then enables the [G] to work for RewriteRule. (Have not yet verifited that Redirect is fixed also.)

Source: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/410-errors-returning-404-pages

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by saying that it doesn't work, what status code is returned? 
If you're using any third-party apache modules try disabling them first.

Comment: It acts the same as it would if I put a # in front of the instruction (i.e. it is ignored).  

The server is running cPanel so has any third-party modules that cPanel has by default, but disabling them is not an option (nor is any other blind config changes that may affect other sites).

Comment: Try checking the http status code with the help of: HttpFox addon (firefox) or Chrome developer tools (Control - Shift - I, Network tab)

Comment: Status code is irrelevant here - the line is being ignored. It appears there's an issue with cPanel, which requires an explicit ErrorDocument directive to be specified - see my answer for details.

Comment: Status code is relevant. You should probably always check it in the first place when you have other problems like this one ;-)

Comment: I was checking it - I had the network tools active in two browsers whilst I was setting up and then debugging the config. The request was being passed to the webapp when it should not have been, and thus the entire response (including status) was irrelevant - [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIGO).